# AngularJS watch FileReader().readyState change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code to read a local file in AngularJS.

```
var files = document.getElementById("file");

files.addEventListener("change", handleFile, false);

function handleFile(event) {
    SpinnerService.upload(); // Show loading spinner

    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    $timeout(function() {
        scope.readyState = reader.readyState;
    });

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        // Read the file
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    scope.$watch("readyState", function(newVal) {
        if (newVal == 2) {
            SpinnerService.hide(); // Hide loading spinner
        }
    })
}
```

When the file is being read, `reader.readyState` will change from 0 to 1 then to 2. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readyState).

My code does successfully read the file. However, the `$watch` on `readyState` does not work. Is there any way to watch the change of `readyState`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: instread of using a `$timeout` you could try to set `scope.readyState = 2` in `reader.onload` and then wake up angular with a `scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice agains setting the watch in the handler function, since it will add en new watch every time it gets triggered.
And then you set scope.readyState to reader.readyState which is an actual value,
kind of like setting x = 2 and the wait for it to change to something else.

Try this:

```
// new empty object
scope.reader = {}

var files = document.getElementById("file");
files.addEventListener("change", handleFile, false);

// set watch on object property
scope.$watch("reader.readyState", function(newVal) {
    if (newVal == 2) {
        SpinnerService.hide(); // Hide loading spinner
    }
})

function handleFile(event) {
     SpinnerService.upload(); // Show loading spinner

     var file = event.target.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();

     // set object to reader
     scope.reader = reader;

     reader.onload = function(event) {
         // Read the file
     };

     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 }
```

Also I think wero's comment is the best solution